# Issue with SQL query - always returns null for record bound to other records in same table

Tags: sql

I have my record (on example 1000) which is related to other records as parent using parentid.
I want to select that record when all its "children" are in status Closed!

table is T1:

```
ID       PARENTID     STATUS
1000      null        PENDING
1001      1000        CLOSED
1002      1000        CLOSED
```

I wrote SQL but it returns me null although it shouldn't ("not in" doesn't work very well)

```
SELECT ID
FROM T1
WHERE PARENTID IS NULL AND ID NOT IN (SELECT PARENTID FROM T1 WHERE STATUS!='CLOSED' )
```

But it return's me null although `SELECT PARENTID FROM ID WHERE STATUS!='CLOSED'` does not return 1000.
Why? How to select then if "NOT IN" clause does not work.

Very,very IMPORTANT thing is that I CAN NOT use `"WHERE PARENTID=ID"` although I know that would be solution but I must do it on different way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IN clause will not work with null. Use nvl in your query to get around (Oracle) -

```
select ID from T1 where PARENTID is null and ID not in (select nvl(parentid,0) from T1 where status != 'CLOSED');
```

Or, if you are using db2 -

```
select ID from T1 where PARENTID is null and ID not in (select coalesce(parentid,0) from T1 where status != 'CLOSED');
```

Comment: Yes! COALESCE was the solution!! Thank you! what exactly does this function do? thanks once again

Comment: If the column has null it replaces null with the value you specify, in this case 0 so that you would be able to compare it with "IN" clause.You can not perform !=, =, IN etc on null as null does not equate to either equality or non-equality.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your subquery is returning `NULL`. When ansi_nulls is on, PARENTID <> `NULL` is unknown, so you don't get any rows.

Try this:

```
select ID
from T1
where PARENTID is null and ID not in (
        select isnull(PARENTID, -1)
        from T1
        where status != 'CLOSED'
        )
```

For more info see:

[4 Simple Rules for Handling SQL NULLs](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Advanced+Querying/fourrulesfornulls/1915/)

Comment: Hi, I am using DB2. It seems that this function does not work in DB2. I tried with COALESCE (PARENTID,0) but then it returns error! If I try COALESCE (PARENTID,null) it again returns me empty result. Do you know solution? Thanks for effor

Answer (score 0):

Another way is

```
SELECT ID
FROM T1 T1Name
WHERE PARENTID IS NULL AND 
not exists(select 1 from T1 where ID=T1Name.parentid and status!='CLOSED')
```